# add multiple users from a listfile

Tags: scripts, users

I am trying to add multiple users in linux in with the use of a list file and shell script, but it do not work.

I get an error saying `./userlist: line 3: $1 ambiguous redirect`.

Shell Script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    xargs -n 1 list < $1



   List file: list
    test1
    test2
```

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of the `$1 ambiguous redirect` error is that you are trying to redirect from `$1` which seems to be empty

`$1` is *the first argument* to the script you are running.
When you execute the script, you should provide the filename as a parameter to the script.

Note: It isn't clear from your question how the script will actually add the users.